# How to use smartfilterbar and smarttable?

Tags: sapui5

I have EntitySet and would like to connect to `SmartFilterBar` and `SmartTable`. The EntitySet looks like:

```
<EntitySet Name="I_PMContactCardEmployee" EntityType="EAM_MALFUNCTION_MANAGE.I_PMContactCardEmployeeType" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:searchable="true" sap:content-version="1"/>
```

The EntityType:

```
<EntityType Name="I_PMContactCardEmployeeType" sap:label="Mitarbeiter" sap:content-version="1">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="PersonnelNumber"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="PersonnelNumber" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="8" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:text="EmployeeFullName" sap:label="Personalnummer"/>
    <Property Name="EmployeeFullName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="80" sap:label="Vollständiger Name" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40" sap:label="Vorname" sap:quickinfo="Vorname des Geschäftspartners (Person)"/>
    <Property Name="FamilyName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40" sap:label="Nachname" sap:quickinfo="Nachname des Geschäftspartners (Person)"/>
    <Property Name="Job" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="8" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:label="Stellenschlüssel" sap:quickinfo="Stelle" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="JobName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="25" sap:label="Stellenbezeichnung" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="CompanyCode" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:text="CompanyCodeName" sap:label="Buchungskreis"/>
    <Property Name="CompanyCodeName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="25" sap:label="Name der Firma" sap:quickinfo="Buchungskreis- oder Firmen-Bezeichnung" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="OrganizationalUnit" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="8" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:label="Organisationseinheit"/>
    <Property Name="OrganizationalUnitName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="25" sap:label="OrgEinheitenkurztext" sap:quickinfo="Organisationseinheitenkurztext" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="PhoneNumber" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Telefon" sap:quickinfo="Telefonnummer: Vorwahl+Anschluß" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="NormalizedPhoneNumber" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Telefonnummer" sap:quickinfo="Vollständige Nummer: Vorwahl+Anschluß+Durchwahl" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="MobilePhoneNumber" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Telefon" sap:quickinfo="Telefonnummer: Vorwahl+Anschluß" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="MblNormalizedPhoneNumber" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Telefonnummer" sap:quickinfo="Vollständige Nummer: Vorwahl+Anschluß+Durchwahl" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="DefaultEmailAddress" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="241" sap:label="E-Mail-Adresse"/>
    <Property Name="UserID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="12" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Benutzer-ID" sap:filterable="false"/>
</EntityType>
```

and the view looks like:

```
<smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="smartFilterBar" entitySet="malfunc>I_PMContactCardEmployee" persistencyKey="SmartFilterPKey">
    <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
        <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="PersonnelNumber" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
    </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
</smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
<smartTable:SmartTable id="smartTable_ResponsiveTable" smartFilterId="smartFilterBarr" tableType="ResponsiveTable" editable="false"
    entitySet="malfunc>I_PMContactCardEmployee" useVariantManagement="true" useTablePersonalisation="true" header="Products" showRowCount="true"
    useExportToExcel="false" enableAutoBinding="true" persistencyKey="SmartTablePKey"></smartTable:SmartTable>
```

the service is registered as:

```
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "example.com.smartemployee.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "malfunc": {
            "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/EAM_MALFUNCTION_MANAGE/",
            "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
            "settings": {
                "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
                "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
                "defaultCountMode": "Request"
            },
            "dataSource": "EAM_MALFUNCTION_MANAGE",
            "preload": true
        }
    },
```

to get the data from the service, in the [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) I called:

[image]

and get all of employees.

When I execute the application, `SmartFilterBar` and `SmartTable` is not working correctly.

[image]

It shows just an empty filterbar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you have to bind I_PMContactCardEmployee**Set** instead of I_PMContactCardEmployee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is better to define the ODataModel as the default model.

```
"malfunc": {
        "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/EAM_MALFUNCTION_MANAGE/",
        "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
        "settings": {
            "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
            "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
            "defaultCountMode": "Request"
        },
        "dataSource": "EAM_MALFUNCTION_MANAGE",
        "preload": true
    }
```

Also, assuming that your EntitySet is called "I_PMContactCardEmployeeSet", you have to specifiy that EntitSet in the SmartFilterBar and SmartTable properties:

```
entitySet="I_PMContactCardEmployeeSet"
```